# Ant secureInputHandler: requires user to press enter before accepting input

Tags: ant

I use SecureInputHandler to accept passwords from the end user in ant script, but it forces user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before it allows text input.
Is this expected behavior? Also, I didn't find much documentation on this topic, please feel free to point me to any resources on this.

```
<input message="Please enter password:"  addproperty="password.property">
    <handler classname="org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler" />
</input>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SecureInputHandler requires Ant 1.7.1 or greater (to support the handler) and Java 6 or greater (to provide the Console class).

If you don't have the right Ant version, you'll get an error. If you don't have the right Java version, Ant falls back to the default input handler.

Note that you can also use:

```
<handler type="secure"/>
```

The javadoc and source can be seen [here](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/tools/ant/input/SecureInputHandler.html).

Using Ant 1.8.2 and Java 1.6 in a windows cmd shell, I get this:

```
test:
Please enter password:<cursor here>
```

The password is masked. You type the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Using a Cygwin shell, or Java 1.5 in cmd shell, I get this:

```
test:
    [input] Please enter password:
<cursor here>
```

The password is not masked. You type the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Using Eclipse console, I couldn't get the password to enter at all. I type, it is echoed on the console, I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens.

I notice that in the documentation of the [Input](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html) task, it says:

> IDE behaviour depends upon the IDE: some hang waiting for input, some
>   let you type it in. For this situation, place the password in a
>   (secured) property file and load in before the input task.

In other words, it may not work in an IDE, use a work around.

Comment: Does <handler type="secure"/> work on any particular version of ant, because I got an error when using that.

Answer (score 0):

exec was interfering with the input tasks.
It can be solved by specifying `inputstring=””` in the exec task.
See [exec causes other tasks to hang or leads to strange behaviour of `<input>` tasks](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#input-makes-exec-hang) in the [Ant FAQ](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html).

Comment: Nice job answering a question that you didn't ask ;)

Comment: @sudocode: Sorry mate, your response was very useful and I duly upvoted. But when I asked this question, I had no idea that the solution to my problem would be this. Lesson learnt: I will take the time to read the relevant software's FAQs before asking questions here. Thanks again for helping me out. :)

Comment: No worries at all - I had to laugh, that's all. If you updated your question with the full context (`exec` as well as `input`) then I think your answer will be the best one to accept and could actually help others in future.